# Understanding a piece of code in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to understand the functionality of the following piece of code:

```
val newDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("date", to_date(myDataFrame("start_date")))
          .withColumn("column1", lit(1))
          .select($"pk".as("id"), $"date", $"column1")
```

In my opinion, it does the following 3 steps:

1) creates a new column `date` by converting `myDataFrame("start_date")` into a date object. In `myDataFrame` the column `start_date` has the following format `2017-05-04 10:22:03.0`. So, as far as I understand, `to_date` transforms it *automatically* into a date without the need of passing a format, e.g. `yyyy-MM....`.

2) creates a new column `columns1` and fills it out with `1`.

3) I slightly misunderstand this line `select($"pk".as("id"), $"date", $"column1")`. What is the meaning of `$` and why 3 columns are selected? Does it creates `newDataFrame` with only 3 columns `id`, `date` and `column1`?

Comment: $ is implicit in sqlContexts and $"pk" is thus a shortcut equivalent to myDataFrame("pk") which returns the Column named "pk". .select has a signature accepting Column*, thus you are passing three Column parameters in the .select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1,2 points are correct.

As for the third: $"pk" is the SQL DSL (gotten from the implicit definition, usually something like import spark.implicits._) which is basically the same as col("pk"). It finds a column called pk in the dataframe.

the as function renames the column. So $"pk".as("id") means take the column called pk as a column and rename it id.

So the select basically takes only the pk, date and column1 columns from the dataframe (ignoring everything else) and renames pk to id in the result.